# register data in format json in php

Tags: php, json

I have this code in my php scrip

```
$concatenation= array('idcarde',$idcarde ,'mobile' ,$mobile ,'firstname',$firstname ,'lastname',$lastname ,'jour',$jour ,'mois',$mois ,'annee',$annee ,'adress',$adresse ,'Governora',$Governora);
$P = serialize( $concatenation );
$mabase = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
    if ($mabase) {
        mysql_select_db("mb", $mabase);
    }

    // insere toutes les donness provenant de $_POST
    $sql = " INSERT INTO `test` SET
            `formid` = '" . $formid . "',
            `data` = '" . mysql_escape_string($P) . "',
            `creation_date` = '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s"). "' ";

    @mysql_query($sql, $mabase);
```

this code save data in my table **test**

and in the column **data** I have this result :

```
a:18:{i:0;s:7:"idcarde";i:1;s:8:"00688009";i:2;s:6:"mobile";i:3;s:8:"52199200";i:4;s:9:"firstname";i:5;s:6:"dumas";i:6;s:8:"lastname";i:7;s:6:"alen";i:8;s:4:"jour";i:9;s:2:"05";i:10;s:4:"mois";i:11;s:2:"05";i:12;s:5:"annee";i:13;s:4:"1951";i:14;s:6:"adress";i:15;s:54:"11 rue paris";i:16;s:9:"Governora";i:17;s:5:"france";}
```

I want to know how can we eliminate this value  i:0  i:1 i:2  i:3 ...

I try also with this code :

it saves data in this format :

```
["idtype","CIN","mobile","20390112","idcard","00731429","firstname","samia","lastname","Mejri","email","","gender","M.","deliv_lieu","","deliv_d","","deliv_m","","deliv_y","","birthdate_d","08","birthdate_m","10","birthdate_y","1944","address","36 rue Grece ","city","France","gouv","France","profession","","field","","bank","","agency","","friends","","followers","","blog_url","","website","","civil_status","","nickname","","zipcode",""]
```

but with the previous code it displays like this

```
a:18:{i:0;s:7:"idcarde";i:1;s:8:"00688009";i:2;s:6:"mobile";i:3;s:8:"52199200";i:4;s:9:"firstname";i:5;s:6:"dumas";i:6;s:8:"lastname";i:7;s:6:"alen";i:8;s:4:"jour";i:9;s:2:"05";i:10;s:4:"mois";i:11;s:2:"05";i:12;s:5:"annee";i:13;s:4:"1951";i:14;s:6:"adress";i:15;s:54:"11 rue paris";i:16;s:9:"Governora";i:17;s:5:"france";}
```

and it is what I want but juste I want to eliminate i:0  i:1 i:2 i:3 until i:17

I try now with this code :

```
$concatenation= array('idcarde',$idcarde ,'mobile' ,$mobile ,'firstname',$firstname ,'lastname',$lastname ,'jour',$jour ,'mois',$mois ,'annee',$annee ,'adress',$adresse ,'Governora',$Governora);
$P = serialize( $concatenation );
$M=preg_replace('~i:[0-9];~', '', $P);
$mabase = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
    if ($mabase) {
        mysql_select_db("mb", $mabase);
    }

    // insere toutes les donness provenant de $_POST
    $sql = " INSERT INTO `test` SET
            `formid` = '" . $formid . "',
            `data` = '" . mysql_escape_string($M) . "',
            `creation_date` = '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s"). "' ";

    @mysql_query($sql, $mabase);
```

this code  eliminate from the data  **i:1; i:2;** until **i:9;** but it can't eliminate

for example **i:10; i:11; i:12;**

I try to resolve this problem without success

$M=preg_replace('~i:~;~', '', $P);

I try to change **a:18** by **a:28** with

```
$P = serialize($concatenation) ;
  //$M=preg_replace('~i:[0-9];~', '', $P);
 $M=preg_replace('~i:[0-9]+;~', '', $P);
  $M1=preg_replace('a:[0-9]+~', 'a:28', $M);
```

but it displays error

I find solution using  `$M1=preg_replace('~a:[0-9]+~', 'a:28', $M);`

but I want to say that 28 is the number of element in $P

so I should find the number of element in $P then make this value in a

Comment: '~i:[0-9]+;~' will do more than one digit and match 10, 11, whatever

Comment: thank you for your answer, juste I want to know how can we change a:18  and replace it by a:28 , because when I try to run the script I find always  a:18{..........}

Comment: try making your regex like this ('/i:\d+;/g', '')

Comment: you can count the number of ';' in the line which gives you the number of elements after removing the ints, then do a replace on the a:18 with `/^a:(\d+)/` with `"a:" . $newNum`

Comment: my $newNum=28  and juste I want to know where I should make /^a:(\d+)/

Comment: I find a solution using :  $M=preg_replace('~i:[0-9]+;~', '', $P);
  $M1=preg_replace('~a:[0-9]+~', 'a:28', $M);

Comment: just look at my answer bellow. If you're defining your initial array as `array('idcarde'=>$idcarde ,'mobile'=>$mobile.....` you won't have this problem anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, [`serialize`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) does not serialize to JSON.  If you want JSON, you should be using [`json_encode`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) instead:

```
$P = json_encode($concatenation);
```

**Edit:** This regular expression will remove the `i:<digits>` from the serialized data, but keep in mind that once you remove this you cannot `unserialize` the resulting string anymore, so I'm not sure why you would want to do it:

```
$M = preg_replace('/([{;])i:\d+;/', '$1', $P);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function is not like json_encode, its used for saving variable names with their values, and later you can [universalize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) then everything will be available. for this purpose use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Answer (score 0):

So, the `a:number` there represents the fact that you have an array and the number of elements inside it. All the `i:number;` are the keys of your array. They go all the way up to the number of elements you have - 1 (because it starts with 0)

If you remove the keys it will deserialize like

```
 ['idcarde'] => '00688009'
 ['mobile'] => '5265656'
```

If this is what you're going for then in the initial line

```
$concatenation= array('idcarde',$idcarde ,'mobile' ,$mobile ,'firstname',$firstname ,'lastname',$lastname ,'jour',$jour ,'mois',$mois ,'annee',$annee ,'adress',$adresse ,'Governora',$Governora);
```

just replace every other comma with a `=>` and you're set